# Domino Server-to-Server | Character set translation strange behavior

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Info:
We use different domino server in our environment. All server use our main domino server for mail routing (only server with external access). So all servers have set a relay host to the main server.
Server all have the same version 9.0.1 FP7 installed.

Problem:
When a mail is transferred from on mail.box to the mail.box from main server, strange things happen. The character set is translated and the result is a messed up mail with hieroglyphics.
Good and bad Example is attached.
I have tried all kind of settings in the MIME-Server configuration.

If i manually copy the mail from one mail.box to another, the email is looking OK, so it have to be a setting either in the outbound from the sending server or the inbound from main server.

Any help or tip is appreciated.

[image: Good example]
[image: Bad example]
**Code**

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
On Error Goto ErrorHandling
Const C_BUTTON_NAME = "Save & Send"
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim CurrentDoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim item As NotesItem
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Set CurrentDoc = workspace.CurrentDocument      

LookupPAB = True
Call Initialise_Mail

Dim CopyToAddress As String
Dim BlindCopyToAddress As String
Dim ReplyAddress As String
Dim SendToAddress As String

Dim body As NotesRichTextItem

Call Create_New_MailDoc

Forall Email In Antwort
    Call AddToSendTo(Email)
End Forall


' SendTo address (required)
' Set the From fields
' Specify how I would like the From address to appear

ReplyAddress = |"Logistics@StorTrec.de" <Logistics@StorTrec.de>|


' Call the From function to set the various From fields
Call AddToFrom(ReplyAddress)

' Your customization of MailDoc starts here.  Set the Subject field and contents of the Body field
MailDoc.Subject = currentdoc.FieldGetText("MailSubject")

If currentdoc.fieldgettext("priority") = "1" Then MailDoc.Importance = "1"

Set doc = currentdoc.Document

Set body = doc.GetFirstItem("MailBody")

Call Maildocbody.appendrtitem(body)

If currentdoc.fieldgettext("Protocol") = "yes" Then 

    Call MailDocBody.AddNewLine(2)
    Call MailDocBody.AppendText("From: " & currentdoc.fieldgettext("from2"))
    Call MailDocBody.AddNewLine(1)
    Call MailDocBody.AppendText("Sent: " & currentdoc.fieldgettext("sent2"))
    Call MailDocBody.AddNewLine(1)
    Call MailDocBody.AppendText("To: " & currentdoc.fieldgettext("to2"))
    Call MailDocBody.AddNewLine(1)
    Call MailDocBody.AppendText("Subject: " & currentdoc.fieldgettext("Subject2"))
    Call MailDocBody.AddNewLine(2)
    Dim itemB As NotesItem
    Set itemB = doc.GetFirstItem( "MailBody2" )
    Call Maildocbody.appendrtitem(itemB)
End If



Call Send_MailDoc

Messagebox "Mail sent!", 64, "Mail sent"
Call currentdoc.Close
```

End Sub

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com. My bet is that you should not use SMTP relaying between the internal servers. Use Notes routing instead.

Comment: Thanks Per, also created that question on serverfault.com. I will also see i we can use Notes routing instead. Thanks for your bet :-)

Comment: Are the messages that you are having problems with being generated by code? Or by humans typing them?  Or both?

Comment: These messages are generated by code (lotusscript).

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: added sample code on top. This code uses Scriptlibrary "MailScript": https://www.agecom.com.au/mailscript